# How to check validity of an Ubuntu installation via debootstrap?

Tags: 14.04, server, security, debootstrap

My goal is to set up an Ubuntu Server installation via debootstrap from another Ubuntu installation and to be sure that this new installation is a correct Ubuntu installation without modifications. When I execute

```
debootstrap trusty /mnt http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I get the response

```
 Valid Release signature (key id 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32)
```

But how does this release signature is checked? Against what other key? Or to ask in a different kind: How can I be sure that the downloaded package for debootstrap is valid and was not modified on its way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validity of the packages is checked against a keyring which can be explicitly specified with the `--keyring=KEYRING` option of `debootstrap` (see `man debootstrap` for details).

If omitted `debootstrap` uses system keyrings which you can easily install with `[name]-keyring` packages in `synaptic`/`apt-get` and (only slightly more complicated) from source.

If `debootstrap` tells you that the package is valid there's a high change that it is. If you mistrust `debootstrap` or a library which it uses for the validation, you need to perform a sophisticated security review based on the source code.

Comment: So if I omit the `--keyring` option, Ubuntu will use the system keyring from `/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg`? How can I verify this key, is there another site to download it from (maybe with SSL-encryption), to compare it with the one provided by `apt-get`?

Comment: It must have been installed either during installation of Ubuntu (like `ubuntu-keyring`) which can be verified in the boot menu of the live distribution or is is installed with `apt-get` which verifies packages (including the `-keyring` packages) with PGP.

Comment: It has been installed during installation of Ubuntu, but this installation was done by the hoster of the server, which I don't trust. So I'm searching for a way to verify this key...

Comment: I see. Sounds like a tricky scenario. Maybe you'll get more input if you ask/search for existing answers for a more abstract question, like "How to verify a PGP key on an untrusted system?". I'm pretty sure that you have to do it outside the system, e.g. in a live system, which is definitely out of the scope of `debootstrap`.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I'll try that. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

If someone searches for more details:
I solved my problem with the fingerprints of the keyfiles (you can get them with `apt-key finger`) and compared them with other (secure) systems.

Maybe helpful is this thread: [How do I know my system updates are trustworthy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236037/how-do-i-know-my-system-updates-are-trustworthy)